# How add in listview from an author listview?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How do I add items from a `ListView` to another `ListView`?

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help ) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Show us code you have tried.

Comment: @ Michael Z I have no idea about this operation !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you provide code, I don't think anyone can help you much other than providing direction. And your question is unclear - do you mean adding a listview inside the author listview? Or make a new listview that is similar to the author listview?

Comment: add the recording of a listview to another listview

Comment: Could you provide some code? On my phone now, but you essentially want to make use of `ListView.Items.Add(your Item)` in a loop. There's probably a one-liner though.